# How to iterate over collection of DataRow without having to strongly type it?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, batch-processing, datarowcollection

I have an Excel input file that I need process for the next flow. The current setup is that it imports the Excel into an Azure function to retrieve the data then proceeds to process it. The business logic aspect is mentioned below. The Azure Function will later on be triggered manually or by blob trigger for processing.

Essentially, one of the main requirements is to make the processing aspect of it generic. Generic in the sense that the business logic needs to be capable enough to split the input file into multiple files defined by "custom column(s)". For instance, person "A" wants to group the input file by one column but person "B" may want to group by another column or person "C" may want to group by multiple columns. **Also just to add on top of the somewhat complex nature of things, the input files given may not always have the same column names also but for now this can be ignored and can be assumed that the file given has the same column names each time**. Any advice?

Requirement: Group the rows based on dynamic input (which tells what to group it by). Currently the dynamic input aspect of it can be done in ANY way (no requirements on this part, can be any format or whatever). The "dynamic input" just tells the business logic what to split the files based on.

```
Input File:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 5271D9E9   | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 111       | Bob       | EST
| 5271D9E9   | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 111       | Ann       | EST
| 5271D9E9   | Bar                 | State 2, Status 3 | 222       | Mike      | PST
| 394B044    | Fooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 222       | Mike      | PST
| 394B044    | Dooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Bob       | EST
| D94321B    | Dooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Ann       | EST
| 9E4371A    | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Bob       | EST
```

Example: Given the input above, person "A" wants separate files for RunbookName thus the output for person "A" is:

```
File 1:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 5271D9E9   | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 111       | Bob       | EST
| 5271D9E9   | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 111       | Ann       | EST
| 9E4371A    | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Bob       | EST

File 2:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 5271D9E9   | Bar                 | State 2, Status 3 | 222       | Mike      | PST

File 3:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 394B044    | Dooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Bob       | EST
| D94321B    | Dooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Ann       | EST

File 4:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 394B044    | Fooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 222       | Mike      | PST
```

Example: Given the original input above, person "C" may want separate output files for RunbookName AND Architect thus the output is:

```
File 1:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 5271D9E9   | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 111       | Bob       | EST
| 394B044    | Dooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Bob       | EST

File 2:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 5271D9E9   | Bar                 | State 2, Status 3 | 222       | Mike      | PST
| 394B044    | Fooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 222       | Mike      | PST

File 3:
| ActivityId | RunbookName         | Result            | ProjectID | Architect | TimeZone
|------------|---------------------|-------------------|-----------|-----------|----------
| 5271D9E9   | Foo                 | State 2, Status 1 | 111       | Ann       | EST
| D94321B    | Dooey               | State 2, Status 1 | 333       | Ann       | EST
```

Currently I'm having an issue with this piece of code:

```
//Get all rows that satisfies queryFilter condition
EnumerableRowCollection results = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("RunbookName") == "RunbookName");
```

I want to achieve something like so, assuming we know the datatype of RunbookName which is provided from dynamic input file the user provides:

```
//Get all rows that satisfies queryFilter condition
EnumerableRowCollection results = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<dynamic.DataType>(dynamic.ColumnName) == dynamic.ColumnName);
```

Or even better try to do something like this without having to strongly type it in order to get the value:

```
//Get all rows that satisfies queryFilter condition
EnumerableRowCollection results = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field(dynamic.ColumnName) == dynamic.ColumnName);
```

Thanks for taking a look at the question.

Comment: `DataRow.Field<T>` is an extension method. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs,33

It may be possible to write your own extension method without the `T` to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that the custom ColumnName is a `string`? Or could it be other custom types?

Comment: @ArunM - Yes. Usually all the column names are a string datatype for the most part, so I think this is a safe assumption.

Comment: Why don't you simply use indexer to access column values: *Equals(x[dynamicColumnName], dynamicValue)*?